# How can I update multiple rows of a database in one query using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to update multiple rows in a table using Laravel Eloquent. But unfortunately, the code below updates only one row. Please what am I doing wrong? Could someone help out please? Cheers

```
public function updateMultipleRows()
{
    $accounts = DB::table('payments')->where('inv_status', 1)->get();
    if (count($accounts) > 0) {
        foreach ($accounts as $account) {
            payments::where('id', $account->id)->update([
                'earning' => $account->earning += ($account->interest / 100) * $account->inv_amount,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this line `'earning' => $account->earning += ($account->interest / 100) * $account->inv_amount,`. There may not += rather only +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to rethink what you are storing. It seems like `earning` is a derived value based on other values in the database and it's a bad idea to store it directly.

If you must (for whatever reason) do this then you can try something like:

```
payments::where('inv_status', 1)
    ->update([
        'earning' => DB::raw('earning + (interest / 100) * inv_amount')
     ]);
```

Comment: Waoh! Great code. You made my day apokryfos. This worked like white charm. Thanks man. you are great. Many thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel>8 then you can use `upsert` which is very simple to use.

```php
$accounts = Payments::where('inv_status', 1)
                   ->get()
                   ->map(function($account){
                         return  [
                             'earning' => $account->earning + ($account->interest / 100) * $account->inv_amount,
                             'id' => $account->id 
                         ]                    
                    });

Payments::upsert($accounts, ['earning'], ['id']);
```

Check this link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts